# Does controlling night-time light for house plants improve their health?

Tags: houseplants, light

I keep a few dozen assorted plants under fluorescent lighting in my basement, because the light isn't very good at the windows. I have always left the light on day and night, but now that I think about it, that is not very natural for plant growth. Would the health of my plants be improved by controlling the light during the night?

Comment: Temperate / high latitude plants receive much less light during the winter naturally. I don't really know the answer, but I would be surprised if turning the lights off for 10 hours did much harm. Not sure if it would *help*, but you'd save a bit of electricity and add a little life to your lamps.

Comment: I assumed not. I erected some grow lamps for seeds (peppers and broccoli so far - MrsWinwaed may add tomatoes soon) at the weekend and chose an 18hr on / 6hr off cycle. However I would be interested in answer specifics...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [lot](http://www.globalsciencebooks.info/JournalsSup/images/Sample/PS_4%281%295-17o.pdf) [of](http://symposium.cshlp.org/content/25/221.extract) research has been done on this and most of the results vary by species. Every plant has a [photoperiod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoperiodism) or the number of hours of light it is used to receiving in a day.  Short day length plants can have stunted growth as they depend on day length to trigger flowering and fruit/seed production.  Day neutral or 12 hour plants like most tropicals can do better.
From this [site](http://www.tropgard.com/general-plant-care-info/317-light-and-your-plants)

> Most foliage plants originate along the equator, where plants get
>   about 12 hours of high intensity light year-round. Many of these
>   plants grow better under 24 hour light than under 12 hour light as the
>   longer light periods enable plants to compensate for the low intensity
>   of artificial light, by absorbing light over a long period. Certain
>   annual bedding plants may receive enough light in order to bloom
>   indoors under continuous lighting. Some plants that do particularly
>   well under 24 hour lighting are Swiss cheese plant (Monstera
>   deliciosa), coleus, cissus, schefflera and cacti. Continuous light
>   also speeds up growth of many slow growing, flowering plants like
>   orchids and cacti. In this way, they can be brought to maturity much
>   quicker. Some plants do well either both 12 and 24 hour days,
>   including philodendrons, English ivy, pothos and dieffenbachia. Under
>   continuous lighting, they tend to keep their lower leaves longer.
>   Spider plant (Chlorophytum spp) grows best with 12 hours of light.

My interpretation of the research is that tropicals will do fine under 24 hours a day continuous light but plants like tomatoes might suffer.  The no risk method is to have the lights on for 20 out of 24 hours.