# Have fluorescent lights in both rooms. How to protect Dumb Cane/Dieffenbachia?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, light

From http://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/dieffenbachia

> Light
>   Another false belief about Dieffenbachia's is that they need very little light. This is actually wrong, light shade is acceptable but nothing darker. To maintain a healthy plant you should be giving indirect bright light. Too bright however and the leaves will scorch, too dark and you will be left with a leggy and sickly looking plant.

We have to light at least one light even during the daytime in our rooms. Rooms are small. Light spreads everywhere.

I have dumb cane. How do I protect it from the tubelight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dieffenbachia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dieffenbachia) will grow under any kind of light.  There is no need to protect it from interior light even if it is on 24 hours a day.  See my answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/3279/499).

I believe when you write about "tubelight" you mean fluorescent lights. There is no quantity of lights or length of artificial day light that will burn or scorch leaves as long as they are at least four feet from the light source.